# Image Picker not working in React Native app, why?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've installed react-native-image-picker successfully, for a fresh react native app, linked it and given right permissions via the info.plist file to access camera, photos etc...

I'm using the code from the ReadMe on react-native-image-picker page, but i receive an error

When attempting to openGallery() i get the following warning and no image library opens:

**Possible unhandled Promise Rejection TypeError; undefined is not a function (near...reactNativeImagePicker.default.launchImageLibrary...)**

Here's my code:

```
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';
.....

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      fileURL: '',
    }
  }

   //function
   openGallery = async () => {
      const options = {
        mediaType: 'video'
      }

    ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary(options, (response) => {
      console('Response = ', response);

      if(response.didCancel){
        console.log('User cancelled image picker');
      }
      else{
       this.setState({ fileURL: response.uri });
      }
    });
 }

render() {
  return (
   <View style={styles.container}>      
    <Button 
       style={{margin: 20}}
       onPress={this.openGallery}
       title='Open Gallery'
       backgroundColor='blue'
    />
   </View>

);

 }   
}
```

Its run of the mill boiler plate code. Whats going on?

@BoredKid, i get this in my console log:

for (ImagePicker):

```
{showImagePicker: ƒ}
showImagePicker: ƒ showImagePicker(options, callback)
__proto__: Object
```

for (ImagePicker.showImagePicker);

```
ƒ showImagePicker(options, callback) {
      if (typeof options === 'function') {
        callback = options;
        options = {};
      }

      return ImagePickerManager.showImagePicker((0, _objectS…
```

Comment: Is this on a simulator or real device? ios, android or both?

Comment: on the iOs simulator on the Mac (iPhone X), not using Expo at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated with new input: your `ImagePicker` object do not have `launchImageLibrary` nor `launchCamera`. There is a problem with you installation ... Maybe the installation didn't work properly or there is a step you made wrong. Let's try to reinstall and we'll see it the problem persist

Comment: Perfect, rolled back to v0.27.0 from Oct2018 and all is ok :D  Still have NO idea why the latest v0.28.0 isn't working when i followed exactly the same process to install. Now the 'fun' begins: react-native-video-processing

Comment: Thanks for helping me dig a little deeper into the issue :)

Comment: not just reinstalling, I had to make sure I installed the latest version, for me the latest version is:   "react-native-image-picker": "^3.3.2",

Answer (score 3):

Instead of writing

`import { ImagePicker } from 'react-native-image-picker',`

you should declare ( In the same place )...

`var ImagePicker = require('react-native-image-picker');`

This worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

The module does not have a default export. You need to use a named export:

`import * as ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';`

or

`import {launchImageLibrary} from 'react-native-image-picker';`

Answer (score 1):

I solve this error by installing the latest version, for me it was

"react-native-image-picker": "^3.3.2",

and also using example code from repository:
https://github.com/react-native-image-picker/react-native-image-picker/blob/main/example/src/App.js

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, Image} from 'react-native';
import cameraImage from '../../../../assets/icons/camera.png';
import galleryImage from '../../../../assets/icons//gallery.png';
import {TouchableWithoutFeedback} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import * as ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';
import {PermissionsAndroid} from 'react-native';
const ImagePicker = () => {
  const [responseCamera, setResponseCamera] = React.useState(null);
  const [responseGallery, setResponseGallery] = React.useState(null);

  const openCameraWithPermission = async () => {
    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,
        {
          title: 'App Camera Permission',
          message: 'App needs access to your camera ',
          buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',
          buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
          buttonPositive: 'OK',
        },
      );
      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        ImagePicker.launchCamera(
          {
            mediaType: 'photo',
            includeBase64: false,
            maxHeight: 200,
            maxWidth: 200,
          },
          (response) => {
            console.log(response);
            setResponseCamera(response);
            setResponseGallery(null);
          },
        );
      } else {
        console.log('Camera permission denied');
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-around',
        margin: 4,
      }}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => openCameraWithPermission()}>
        {responseCamera === null ? (
          <Image style={styles.icon} source={cameraImage} />
        ) : (
          <Image style={styles.icon} source={{uri: responseCamera.uri}} />
        )}
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() =>
          ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary(
            {
              mediaType: 'photo',
              includeBase64: false,
              maxHeight: 200,
              maxWidth: 200,
            },
            (response) => {
              setResponseGallery(response);
              setResponseCamera(null);
            },
          )
        }>
        {responseGallery === null ? (
          <Image style={styles.icon} source={galleryImage} />
        ) : (
          <Image style={styles.icon} source={{uri: responseGallery.uri}} />
        )}
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  icon: {
    height: 50,
    width: 50,
  },
});

export default ImagePicker;
```

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

Comment: thx for the example, i was dealing with non-opening camera and i was missing this PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA logic

Answer (score 0):

this is same error occur when i am install react-native-image- picker default off version 2 when i am change the version of following method npm install react-native-image-picker@3.3.2