# react-native-image-picker vs expo ImagePicker

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-camera, react-native-image-picker

I have tried many attempts to get react-native-image-picker up and working with my RN app. I am using Expo and VS Code and am not running the app with Xcode or Android Studio. There seems to be many options to getting the camera roll available in an app and I am not sure which is the best path to take. None seem to be working for me so I would like to pick the best path and focus on making that one route work.

I am following the documentation: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-image-picker

Things I have tried:

- React Native Camera Roll
- Expo ImagePicker
- expo-image-picker
- react-native-image-picker
- react-images-upload
- react-native-photo-upload

My code:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Text, CameraRoll } from 'react-native'
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';
// import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

const PicturesScreen = ({navigation}) => {
    const [pictures, setPictures] = useState([]);

getPermissionAsync = async () => {
    if (Constants.platform.ios) {
      const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        alert('Sorry, we need camera roll permissions to make this work!');
      }
    }
};

useEffect(() => {
    getPermissionAsync();
}, []);

selectPhotoTapped = () => {
   const options = {
      quality: 1.0,
      maxWidth: 500,
      maxHeight: 500,
      storageOptions: {
        skipBackup: true,
      },
    };

    ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, response => {    
      if (response.didCancel) {
        console.log('User cancelled photo picker');
      } else if (response.error) {
        console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
      } else if (response.customButton) {
        console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
      } else {
        let source = {uri: response.uri};
        console.log('source: ' + source);
        // You can also display the image using data:
        // let source = { uri: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + response.data };

        setPictures({
          picture: source
        });
      }
    });
  };


return (
    <View style = {styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.buttonContainerPhoto} onPress={()=> selectPhotoTapped()}> 
            <Text style={styles.buttonText} >
                Upload Photos 
            </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity> 

    <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.buttonContainer} onPress={()=> navigation.navigate('NextScreen')}> 
            <Text style={styles.buttonText} >
                Next 
            </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        ...
    }
});

export default PicturesScreen;
```

I have made sure to link the packages, I have also uninstalled and reinstalled and started from scratch a few times. I have downgraded the version to make it work but I still continue to get one of these error messages:

> react-native-image-picker: NativeModule.ImagePickerManager is null

or

> Can not read property 'showImagePicker' of undefined.

or

> undefined is not an object(evaluating 'imagepickerManager.showimagepicker')

Is it causing issues because I am using Expo? Should I just be using CameraRoll with react-native?

Comment: I'm using RN v0.60.4 with react-native-image-picker v1.0.1.   Works fine on android emulator and ios simulator.   It very well could be an issue with expo as you eluded to.   Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54352838/image-picker-not-working-in-react-native-app-why?rq=1

Comment: hum. yea I am on react-native: 0.59.8 and have tried running it on v0.26.0 and 0.28.0. I wonder if it could also be an issue with running it on RN < 0.60...

Comment: If you're using Expo, you must use expo-image-picker: https://docs.expo.io/versions/v35.0.0/sdk/imagepicker/ Anything that requires the use of `react-native link` will not work with Expo, unless stated that it is already bundled with Expo

Comment: thank you, if you would like to post this as the answer I can mark it as correct @zaytrix

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [expo-image-picker](http://docs.expo.io/versions/v35.0.0/sdk/imagepicker) if you're using Expo.

Anything that requires the use of `react-native link` will not work with Expo, unless stated that it is already included in Expo.

Comment: any idea how to have the camera option available in the gallery picker. Something like what twitter and others do?

Comment: @MohamedDaher you can use ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync() (https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/?redirected#imagepickerlaunchcameraasyncoptions) to launch the camera

Comment: I think you did not get my problem. I need to have a camera button(switch thumb) as an item inside the gallery. This is the modern way of asking the user to input an image (giving them both options to select image or take picture)

Comment: @MohamedDaher those apps use their own custom gallery instead of the native gallery. expo-image-picker only launches the native one. What you can do with this is create a custom component which has a button to open the native camera, and a button to open the native gallery. You would need to look into another option to get the images from the gallery to create your own custom gallery with a button to launch the camera, which may not be possible with the Expo managed workflow.

Comment: Yeah that was what i thought and its fair enough since using expo you agree to their stack offering and building custom specs would require you to build natively or at least without expo. Thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck with the same issue, and now I have resolved this. *React native cli* and *expo cli* both have some package differences. Similarly image-picker for both works differently.

For expo cli, you can check the documentation here: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/#__next

You can try for uploading image via camera using `ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync` and from photo library using `ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync`.

While in react-native cli I was able to write a single function to choose from both camera and photo library but could not find a way for the same in expo yet.