# Expo Image Picker vs RN-image picker

Tags: expo, react-native, react-native-web

I am quite new to RN . I know this question is being repeated but I didn't quite get ans I was looking for there .
So my current project uses
expo for web and react-native cli for the android set up .
I want to add an image-picker to the project.
I see two options at my side .

1. RN-image-picker
2. expo-image-picker

I have some issues and some questions !!

1. Is RN-native-image picker comaptible with web ??

   - I think its not ,there are two resons I think that ,this lib uses Nativemodules, which
     won't be bundled for web and its giving undefined error for NativeModules when I run with
     web while it works fine on android .
2. Should I use expo-image-picker when I am creating a android build with react-native cli ??

- The build doesn't give errors and it shouldn't ,but when I click on upload image ,app
  crashes after I select image.I read the docs and github for the issue.Many people pointed
  out its ram allocation issue,which can be sorted with disbaling "Dont keep activities" in
  developer's option,which I haven't tried yet .

3. Also on web ,the following code snippet returns base64 as uri,is it default behaviour ??

I am using this code snippet for expo-image-picker,which ends up crashing app when I build app with rn cli,but doesn't seem to cause issues with expocli build.But I want to use expo for web and rn for android.
Also on web ,the following code snippet returns base64 as uri,is it default behaviour ??

```js
const pickImage = async () => {
        try{
        let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
            mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
            allowsEditing: true,
            aspect: [4, 3],
            quality: 1,
            base64:false
        })
         if(!result.isCancelled)return result.uri ;
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err) ;
    }
       
 }
```

So what should I do in this case,use expo-image-picker as it seems to be compatible with all platforms/both ?
Any kind of input would be helpful !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a fan of Expo, and I don't have experience with that but I try to answer to your question that can be.

> Is RN-native-image picker comaptible with web ??

You have right, the library supports only mobile devices.

> Should I use expo-image-picker when I am creating an android build with react-native cli ??

From expo documentation, I read that but I know also that sometimes the `rn-cli` and expo has some package differences, and this [answer proves](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65353703/10854225) that.

> Expo never locks you in, you can "eject" at any time and your project will just be a typical native project with the React Native and Expo SDK packages that your app is using installed and configured.

I don't know what the exception, and maybe the solution that you put in your answer work well, but maybe is possible to have some dependency mismecc? Such as a none object on the Web app? or something like that.

> Also on web ,the following code snippet returns base64 as uri,is it default behaviour ??

This looks like be an bug and [this issue on github](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/9984) maybe can confirm my idea

Comment: Thanks for answering all the questions,it's really helpful.

Comment: Considerer to mark it as a correct answer :)